# Grails 3 bootstrap - service doesn't create db entry

Tags: grails, grails-services

I have a very simple service set up to create an entry in a Postgres table, and I use it in Bootstrap.groovy for my Grails 3 web-app.

```
// CompanyService
public Company createCompany(String name) {
    Company company = new Company(name: name)
    company.save()
    return company
}

// BootStrap
def init = {
    companyService.createCompany('My Company')
}
```

Well, at startup I cannot see `My Company` entry, no matter if the service is transactional or not.
Instead, if using the same line for example in a controller, it works as expected. Am I missing something here?

Comment: what happens when you use `company.save(failOnError: true)`? Do you see an exception?

Comment: No exception or different result if using `failOnError:true` nor `flush: true`, sorry for not pointing it out first..

Comment: I found the issue by calling in BootStrap `new Company(name: 'My Company').save(failOnError: true)` in place of `companyService`: it was related to a domain class constraint set for `name` property.
But i really can't tell why no exception is printed using the service..

Answer (score 0):

Have you called your service inside `bootstrap`?

```
class BootStrap {

   def companyService

   def init = { servletContext ->
      companyService.createCompany('My Company')
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how my BootStrap looks like.
However I found was my issue was, i added a comment under my question above.